# Multiple containers per page

Tags: reactjs, redux

I really like the separation between Components (have no idea about infrastructure, get all their data from props) and Containers (make all infrastructure stuff and pass props to Components) but I've encountered a situation where it feels quite problematic.

I have two logically separate pieces of code in my container. So it feels natural to split my container into two but I'm not sure how to manage it. What should I do with those subcontainers? Possible ways to go:

1. Put them in components folder under the folder of main component (that represent a page). But putting containers (subcontainers but anyway) into components folder feels wrong
2. Put them into Containers folder in folder by Page name (page container will just render these two subcontainers). Seems like a reasonable way to go but I've never encountered this kind of implementation.

Comment: Solution two seems fine. This is more of a preference than guide. Just go with what fits your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will highly recommend you to check [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate). The way that they structure the files are very good.

Answer (score 0):

Container components:

> May contain both presentational and container components** inside but usually don’t have any DOM markup of their own except for some wrapping divs, and never have any styles.

Please see this article by Dan Abramov on what 
[presentational and container components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.r6rscivg9) should contain. He explains his reasoning for this point at the bottom of the article.

Comment: That article doesn't address having multiple containers per page.